# Apache POI java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError reading an excel file

Tags: java, excel, exception, apache-poi, read-write

I'm having some problem trying to read an Excel file, using Apache POI

Here's the exception:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory$CreateWorkbook0

I've done some research and found many stackoverflow solutions, that i tried to apply without results.
I also checked all the imported jars under the buil path -> Library -> maven dependency and all the suggested jars are in place.
The dependency added to the project are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm i missing something?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't mix and match Apache POI jars between versions! You need to get all of them from the same version

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I've updated the major version (poi, poi-ooxml, poi-ooxml-schemas) to version 4.1.2. Moved a little forward. Now the problem seems different: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Foglio1 from [Module "deployment.app.ear.app-web.war" from Service Module Loader]
The exception is raised from 

Class clazz = Class.forName(workbook.getSheetName(0));

Can't find other lib version problem.

Comment: Solved the second problem too.
This online example  (http://learningprogramming.net/java/spring-mvc/import-excel-file-in-spring-mvc-framework/) contains an error:

Sheet sheet = getSheetWithName(classname);
Class clazz = Class.forName(workbook.getSheetName(0));

Should be: 
Sheet sheet = getSheetWithName(workbook.getSheetName(0));
Class clazz = Class.forName(classname);
@Gagravarr Thank you again for the Dependencies info.